# Lazy load into another page

Tags: javascript, scroll, lazy-loading, loading, fullpage.js

I'm using fullPage.js and am wanting to achieve the affect used here: http://www.fantasy.co/work/microsoft-touch

After 5/6 scrolls you can see that youre taken to to another page, that or potentially isolated section, or the scrollbar's specific to every few sections. Anybody know how they've achieved that? Is it possible with fullPage.js?

Comment: We don't ask those kind of question here where we recommend something off site. But anyway, look in to [snap points](https://css-tricks.com/introducing-css-scroll-snap-points/). Btw, i thought that page behaved poorly, couldn't swipe left or right, they converted it to down/up scroll - which lead to me not being able to go back